# An item with the same key has already been added - Just in Release mode

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, release

Experts,

I'm getting this **System.ArgumentException** (*An item with the same key has already been added*) at the very first use of an entity framework function at runtime.
The strange thing: If I'm using debug mode, it works fine. After compiling the same code without any changes made in **release mode**, it crashes immediatly with exception mentioned at top of this post.

Does anyone know more about such a strange behaviour? How can I fix it? I cannot roll out a debug version to my customer :(

Exception is thrown at this point:

```
try
{
  var blub = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(QueryString);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // ...
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boo
lean add)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadRelationshi
pTypes()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAs
sembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boo
lean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boo
lean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boo
lean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boo
lean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boo
lean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollec
tion edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionar
y`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(Object
ItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAs
semblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Typ
e type, Assembly callingAssembly)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](Stri
ng commandText, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Object[] paramete
rs)
```

Comment: Which version and flavour (POCO, Code First, etc) of the EF do you use?

Comment: There should be more info in Stack trace. Have you possibly cut anything?

Comment: just created a model from an existing mssql database. no poco.

Comment: what's the code like and the environment? when you are executing the dbug version is that in an identical environment (number of users and so forth)? is it web or desktoip?

Comment: i've removed the last part (the call of my first entity function), because thats company related stuff and should not be read here ;)

Comment: same environment in debug and release. it's a console application

Comment: if you don't want to post your company's related code you have to compile a minimal sample and post it here, nobody will understand what the problem is just from this stack trace

Comment: why? it's just a function where **var context = new SecretEntityModelClass();** is called. thats all. thats the end of stacktrace.

Comment: err, i have to correct myself. exception is thrown at this point: var blub = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(QueryString);

Comment: Make sure that you access `ObjectContext` from a single thread (it's not thread-safe). Multi-threaded access to EF objects could cause such errors in release builds due to some differencies of compiler and JIT behavior.

Comment: You write about 'the very first use of an entity framework function at runtime'. Do you mean that after one exception is thrown the app continues to work fine?

Comment: no it crashes. i found out, that ExecuteStoreQuery causes the problem. after removing it, the app works fine O_o

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe you should post a repro on connect site. It can still be somehow related to edmx and mappings, because ExecuteStoreQuery uses mappings to materialize query results.

Comment: but just an integer should be mapped there.. nothing special. the script just performs "SELECT @isUpdated". isUpdated contains 1 or 0. cant imagine, that that can cause exceptions during mapping.. strange thing.. cannot debug it, because this error just comes up in release mode :(

Comment: Well, I understand you doubt, but the source code suggests that the EF tries to load mappings metadata each time you use the method regardless of the type parameter. I suppose they simply didn't consider introducing optimizations for such rare cases worthy of doing. However, the error still cannot be treated as an expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you get the error even if you make a **clean release build** (I mean no binaries before running the build, source code only). If you don't, then fix your project setup (isolate debug and release build target folders for example).

If the error occurs only once and after that the app works fine, you must have some synchronization issues. Although it's quite strange, since metadata loading seems to be synchronized. But in any case, EF objects are not thread-safe. Do not use them in cross-thread scenarios.

If the above said doesn't help, then maybe the results of my research will help you. Here's an excerpt from the EF source code that relates to the error:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// <copyright file="ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.cs" company="Microsoft">
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// 
// @owner       [....]
// @backupOwner [....] 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Reflection;

namespace System.Data.Metadata.Edm 
{
  /// <summary> 
  /// Class for representing a collection of items for the object layer.
  /// Most of the implemetation for actual maintainance of the collection is
  /// done by ItemCollection
  /// </summary> 
  internal sealed class ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader :
      ObjectItemAssemblyLoader
  { 
    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// This method loads all the relationship type that this entity takes part in
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="entityType"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param> 
    private void LoadRelationshipTypes() 
    {
      foreach (EdmRelationshipAttribute roleAttribute in
               SourceAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EdmRelationshipAttribute), false /*inherit*/)) 
      {
        // Check if there is an entry already with this name
        if (TryFindNullParametersInRelationshipAttribute(roleAttribute))
        { 
          // don't give more errors for these same bad parameters
          continue; 
        } 

        bool errorEncountered = false; 

        // return error if the role names are the same
        if (roleAttribute.Role1Name == roleAttribute.Role2Name)
        { 
          SessionData.EdmItemErrors.Add(new EdmItemError(
              System.Data.Entity.Strings.SameRoleNameOnRelationshipAttribute(roleAttribute.RelationshipName, roleAttribute.Role2Name),
                       null)); 
          errorEncountered = true; 
        }


        if (!errorEncountered)
        {
          AssociationType associationType = new AssociationType(
            roleAttribute.RelationshipName, roleAttribute.RelationshipNamespaceName,
            roleAttribute.IsForeignKey, DataSpace.OSpace); 
          SessionData.TypesInLoading.Add(associationType.FullName, associationType);
          TrackClosure(roleAttribute.Role1Type); 
          TrackClosure(roleAttribute.Role2Type); 

          // prevent lifting of loop vars 
          string r1Name = roleAttribute.Role1Name;
          Type r1Type = roleAttribute.Role1Type;
          RelationshipMultiplicity r1Multiplicity = roleAttribute.Role1Multiplicity;
          AddTypeResolver(() => 
            ResolveAssociationEnd(associationType, r1Name, r1Type, r1Multiplicity));

          // prevent lifting of loop vars 
          string r2Name = roleAttribute.Role2Name;
          Type r2Type = roleAttribute.Role2Type; 
          RelationshipMultiplicity r2Multiplicity = roleAttribute.Role2Multiplicity;
          AddTypeResolver(() =>
            ResolveAssociationEnd(associationType, r2Name, r2Type, r2Multiplicity));

          // get assembly entry and add association type to the list of types in the assembly
          Debug.Assert(!CacheEntry.ContainsType(associationType.FullName), "Relationship type must not be present in the list of types"); 
          CacheEntry.TypesInAssembly.Add(associationType); 
        }
      } 
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

The only dictionary used in the method is `SessionData.TypesInLoading`. The key is a combination of `RelationshipName` and `RelationshipNamespaceName`. The funny thing is that a comment says they check for duplicated keys, but the method `TryFindNullParametersInRelationshipAttribute` checks only that the properties of an attribute are not `null`s. I suppose it's a bug.

But more important is that the described error must have occured because somewhere in your assemblies you have more than one `EdmRelationshipAttribute` with equal combinations of `RelationshipName` and `RelationshipNamespaceName` properties. There might be various reasons:

1. Incorrect EDMX file.
2. Impropperly copied assemblies,
3. Release configuration outputing it's build results to the same folder as Debug configuration,
4. Errors in manual generation of EF mapping assemblies,
5. etc.

Unfortunately, catching the name of the broken relationship will be very difficult. You'll probably have to set a breakpoint at `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadRelationshipTypes()` and trace it in disassembly. I would say it will be nearly impossible because the `Dictionary.Insert` method is about to be called **many** times.

If all these still don't suggest the solution, then you do need to prepare a repro of your issue and post it here. Otherwise nobody will be able to help.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. yesterday evening, i found out, that ExecuteStoreQuery causes the exception. dunno why. so it's no problem with edmx or assemblies at all.. :/